# Printing a file path to a label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.8

I am writing a windows application using python where I am trying to get the path to a specific folder in the **C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming** folder and print it to a label. I have tried the filedialog and it only lets me select a file rather than a folder to print to the label.

```py
def getcache():
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="%appdata%", title="Select Cache Folder")
```

This is what I normally use to get a specific file. But I am looking for a folder in this case to print to a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/dialog.html) you can try with askdirectory:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
cache_folder = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="%appdata%", title="Select Cache Folder")
```